# error of consuming more than 7 GB memory even though no large data structure is used in Python on Win7

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7

I am working on python 2.7 to compare two txt files on win7.

I do not use any large data structure. But, it consume more than 7.78 GB memory.
All files are located at local drives.

```
file1 = open(myfile1, 'r')
file2 = open(myfile2, 'r')
result_file1 = open(result_file, 'w')

while 1:
    l1 = file1.readline()
    l2 = file2.readline()
    if (l1 is EOFError or l2 is EOFError):
        break
    if (l1 != l2):
        a_line = l1.strip().split(',')
        b_line = l2.strip().split(',')
        if(a_line[0] != b_line[0] or a_line[1] != b_line[1]):
            print("error " + str(a_line) + " col not match " + str(b_line))
            return (1)     
        error = abs(float(a_line[2]) - float(b_line[2]))/float(a_line[2])
        result_file1.write(a_line[0] + "," + a_line[1]+ "," + a_line[2]
                    + "," + b_line[3] + "," + str(rel_error*100) + "\n")
  result_file1.close()
  file1.close()
  file2.close()
```

The result_file1 is not more than 50 MB.

thanks !

Comment: Which version of python are you using? Tagging as both python2.7 and python3.x is unhelpful

Comment: I think you should close the file. How large are they?

Comment: @aIKid, the file1 and file2 are 3 GB. They are loaded to memory at the same time ? thanks !

Comment: Which specific version of python are you using? I smell a memory leak. Are you perhaps using python3.x where x<3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, in your code there's no obvious reason why it's taking that much memory, though
it's a better idea to use context managers to close the files when the function ends.
As you iterate over the files until one of them fails, it's also a good idea to iterate
both iterators at once. Also note that if you're using python3, you shall use `zip()`
instead of `izip()`, as `izip()` is deprecated.

```
try:
    with open(myfile1, 'r') as file1:
        with open(myfile2, 'r') as file2:
            with open(result_file, 'w') as file3:
                for l1, l2 in izip(file1, file2):
                    if (l1 != l2):
                        a_line = l1.strip().split(',')
                        b_line = l2.strip().split(',')
                        if(a_line[0] != b_line[0] or a_line[1] != b_line[1]):
                            raise Exception("error {} could not match {}".format(a_line, b_line))
                        error = abs(float(a_line[2]) - float(b_line[2]))/float(a_line[2])
                        result_file1.write("{},{},{},{},{}\n".format(a_line[0],
                                                                     a_line[1],
                                                                     a_line[2],
                                                                     b_line[3],
                                                                     rel_error*100)
except Exception as err:
    print err
```

given the code I'm giving here, you should never have more than one line of each file loaded in memory at once. If you still get memory issues, it's either something else in your code that may be misbehaving, or your system not deallocating the memory fast enough.

Comment: I think the reason is pretty obvious. The files are being stored in the memory

Comment: @aIKid: if the OP is correct about the posted file sizes, they still don't add up to 7.78 GB

Comment: well, have a look at the [`readline()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4e243b399307/Lib/_pyio.py#l466) function, it's not loading the whole file in memory, it's only loading one line at a time… which is the whole point of iterating over a file!